# How to loop through section elements to project with ng-content

Tags: angular, typescript, transclusion, angular2-ngcontent

I'm building a stepper and am using "transclusion" with `ng-content` to dynamically grab `section` elements within the stepper tag. The stepper.component view works like this:

```
<ng-content select=".one"></ng-content>
<ng-content select=".two"></ng-content>
<ng-content select=".three"></ng-content>
```

Component usage looks like this:

```
<stepper>
    <section class="one">content here<section>
    <section class="two">content here<section>
    <section class="three">content here<section>
</stepper>
```

However, I'd like to make it dynamic by recognizing the section elements automatically:

```
<ng-content *ngFor="let section of sections; index as i;" select="['section:nth-child(' + i + ')']"></ng-content>
```

**How can I:**

1. get a nodeList of the section elements available to transclude?
2. use ng-content's `select` to target them incrementally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would create a directive like:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[stepper-section]'
})
export class StepperSectionDirective {}
```

then add `stepper-section` attribute to each of sections:

```
<stepper>
    <section stepper-section>content here<section>
    <section stepper-section>content here<section>
    <section stepper-section>content here<section>
</stepper>
```

and finally make use of `@ContentChildren` decorator to query all the sections:

```
@ContentChildren(StepperSectionDirective) sections: QueryList<StepperSectionDirective>;
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/iyakFbPqySsZ8PhnK1qT)**

If you want to loop through content and render it dynamically you can wrap your children with `ng-template` and use `ngTemplateOutlet` directive to render them in StepperComponent:

**html**

```
<app-stepper>
  <ng-template stepper-section>Content 1</ng-template>
  <ng-template stepper-section>Content 2</ng-template>
  <ng-template stepper-section>Content 3</ng-template>
</app-stepper>
```

**stepper-section.directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[stepper-section]'
})
export class StepperSectionDirective {
  hidden = false;

  constructor(public templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) {}
}
```

**stepper.component.ts**

```
@ContentChildren(StepperSectionDirective) sectionDirs: QueryList<StepperSectionDirective>;
```

**stepper.component.html**

```
<button *ngFor="let section of sections; index as i;"
       [class.enabled]="activeSection === i" (click)="goTo(i)">
  Step {{ i + 1 }}
</button>
<div class="content">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let section of sections">
    <ng-template *ngIf="!section.hidden" 
         [ngTemplateOutlet]="section.templateRef"></ng-template>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/Z1u73mhmmQcy5114qVx6?open=app%2Fstepper%2Fstepper.component.ts)**

The difference between these two approaches is that in the first case all child content gets rendered and we only manipulate `display: none` to those steps we want to hide.

In the second approach we have more control on what we want to render and we render only one step at specific time.

Comment: Hey @yurzui! It already works that way actually! `@ViewChild('container', { static: false }) container: ElementRef;` but I'm trying to get away from naming each class incrementally. I just want to dynamically pull them in and display them. Is this possible?

Comment: You do not need to name each class

Comment: Hmm I think I follow. Directive's are required so that ContentChildren can access them and pull them into a QueryList? Without the directive it cannot? (can I make stepper-section components instead?)

Comment: Yes, you can use component

Comment: Thanks Yurzui. The issue is looping through them with ng-content. Would you be able to update your answer with how that looks within the stepper component?

Comment: Yes! It has completely cleared up how to approach this. With one ng-content. The `@ContentChildren` concept is working out great as well for access. Thank you.

Comment: Hey @yurzui I think you may have changed the answer to use ng-template and placed the stepper-section on each one? I'm using one ng-content to get the content within `<stepper>...</stepper>` but ContentChildren has no results. Do you know why?

Comment: Can you reproduce it somewhere?